# For a block matrix of full rank that contains only positive elements, is the determinant of any square partition non-zero?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a $m \times m$ square matrix $M$ that is full rank with each element $m_{i,j} \geq 0$:

$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Suppose that $A$ is a $2\ x \ 2$ square matrix. Is there a theorem that would show $A$ has full rank as well and determinant non-zero? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean when you reference the rank/determinant of a square partition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the example 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$ where the matrix $A$ is the zero matrix.